# How to read user by claim in AAD B2C custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there any option to read azure AD B2C tenant users (local or social) by a claim value such as email address or by custom claim such as `extension_company_user_id` etc.

Actually I need something like below:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingClaimValue">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="company_user_id" PartnerClaimType="extenstion_company_user_id"  />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
            <!-- Optional claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_company_user_id" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Hi @Harun are you looking to get the current logged in user email address or how to [enable the custom attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-custom-attributes) in the custom policy.?

Comment: Actually I want to make email address unique both among local & social accounts. So prior to create new account(local or social) I have to check wether there is already an account with that email address or not. But I can check that only for local accounts i.e., AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress. It would serve my purpose if there would be a method that will consider both local & social accounts.

Comment: A single user can sign up with multiple different approaches. Eg via local email/password, Facebook, Gmail. By default 3 different accounts will get created. The federated IdP accounts do not store the email in B2C by default. So technically even if all of the above used the same email, then only the local account will actually contain the actual email.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that because the claim has no uniqueness constraint. You need to read users by the signInNames property or the userIdentities/alternativeSecurityId property, these have a uniqueness constraint.

This would be valid:

```xml
 <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userEnteredEmail" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress"  />
```

If `extenstion_company_user_id` is going to be unique, and a user identifier, write it to `signInNames.companyUserId`. AAD B2C will automatically register the schema extension when doing so in custom policy.

Then you can read a user like this:

```xml
 <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="company_user_id" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.companyUserId"  />
```